# Unable to create foregroundService in flutter native

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, foreground-service

I'm unable to start the foreground service from native Kotlin code in Flutter.
I have tried this https://github.com/letsdoit07/background_service
and https://medium.com/@burlakovv.ivan/simple-android-foreground-service-in-flutter-for-non-kotlin-developers-31607909a633
but I can't do so.
How can I create it?
I'm using Flutter version 3.3.7.

This part is not working

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            this.startForegroundService(forService)
        } else {
            this.startService(forService)
        }
```

**Update:**
I have solved it. There was a package name issue. I use the same package name in native code. Now it's working fine.